# How to parse a string that contains multiple tokens and multiple delimiters in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing

The string (aka Message) I am trying to parse out looks like this. (It also looks exactly like this when you paste it in Notepad

```
"CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5"
```

I would like to make 5 separate functions that return each of the specific values which would be like `GetCorrelationId`, `GetRFAPI`, `GetCaller`, `GetRqSchema`, and `GetTenantId` and extract out their corresponding values.

How would I do this in C# without using Regex?

Below is the code I have made for the caller (and this method is the same for all other 4 functions) but I have been advised that regex is slow and should not be used by my mentor and the method I have below doesn't even work anyway. Also, my biggest problem with trying to use the regex is that there are multiple delimiters in the message like `',' ' ' and ': ' and ':'`

```
string parseCaller(string message)
            {
                var pattern = @"Caller:(.*)";
                var r = new Regex(pattern).Match(message);
                var caller = r.Groups[1].Value;

                return caller;
            }
```

Expected result should be:

```
GetCorrelationId(message) RETURNS b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
GetRFAPI(message) RETURNS /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment
GetRqSchema(message) RETURNS {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy
GetCaller(message) RETURNS C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1
GetTenantId(message) RETURNS 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5
```

Comment: You say that "regex is slow", well, then your question should say how fast is fast enough, and how you are measuring performance. Apparently you have **extremely difficult** performance requirements if regular expressions are "too slow", so you should focus *all* of your attention on *very carefully measuring every nanosecond*.  Start with that; you *must* set up a repeatable, accurate measurement system if your performance requirements are this strict.

Comment: Accurately measuring the performance of .NET applications is a difficult problem at the sort of level you're talking about here, so you should probably enlist the services of a professional who is an expert in this area who can advise you.

Comment: @EricLippert I would say actually that I CAN use regex however he would prefer other alternatives if that makes it more clear

Comment: Write it both ways and see! (which is more clear)

Comment: It's helpful if you say in the question what your actual requirements are. Your best course of action is: *get the code correct first even if it is slow*.  Write a test suite that verifies correctness.  Then make a performance goal *before* you measure it, and *then* measure it and see if you met your goal. If you did, then you are done and you wasted no time or money doing an unnecessary optimization based on some mythological reasoning about regexes being "slow".

Comment: If it is too slow, *then* ask a question about how to optimize it. You will then be doing experiments from a position of strength: your test suite will ensure that you do not break correctness, and your measurements will detect when you've made things better or worse.

Comment: @AAA Ahaha! Ok, that's such a different word. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these specifications in your question:

> How would I do this in C# without using Regex?

and

> I would like to make 5 separate functions

You can try the below. It's really simple, as you can study your string and use `IndexOf` and `SubString` functions appropriately:

```cs
using System;
class ParseTest
{
    static string GetCorrelationId(string message)
    {
        int i = message.IndexOf(": ") + 2; //length of ": "
        int j = message.IndexOf("Request");
        return message.Substring(i, j-i).Trim();
    }

    static string GetRFAPI(string message)
    {
        int i = message.IndexOf("API: ") + 5; //length of "API: "
        int j = message.IndexOf("Caller");
        return message.Substring(i, j-i).Trim();
    }

    static string GetCaller(string message)
    {
        int i = message.IndexOf("Caller:") + 7; //length of "Caller: "
        int j = message.IndexOf(" CorrelationId");
        return message.Substring(i, j-i).Trim();
    }

    static string GetRqSchema(string message)
    {
        int i = message.IndexOf("RequestedSchemas:") + 17; //length of "RequestedSchemas:"
        int j = message.IndexOf(",  TenantId:");
        return message.Substring(i, j-i).Trim();
    }

    static string GetTenantId(string message)
    {
        int i = message.IndexOf("TenantId:") + 9; //length of "TenantId: "
        return message.Substring(i).Trim();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string m = @"CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
                    Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5";
        Console.WriteLine(GetCorrelationId(m));
        Console.WriteLine(GetRFAPI(m));
        Console.WriteLine(GetCaller(m));
        Console.WriteLine(GetRqSchema(m));
        Console.WriteLine(GetTenantId(m));
    }
}
```

You can run it [here](https://repl.it/repls/WelllitSlightGigabyte).

**EDIT**: Of course you can modify this to use get-only properties, as some other answerers have tried to do.

If, on the other hand, you want to write a parser (*this is kind of lazy one* ), then that's another matter for your researching pleasure.

Comment: you are a god thank you this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this a little differently and create a class that has properties for each value you want to parse from the string. Then we can create a static `Parse` method that creates an instance of the class from an input string, which sets all the properties for you.

If the string always has the same items (CorrelationId, RequestForAPI, Caller, etc) in the same order, we can utilize a simple helper method to `GetValueBetween` two headers.

The code is pretty simple:

```
class MessageData
{
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string RequestForAPI { get; set; }
    public string RequestedSchemas { get; set; }
    public string Caller { get; set; }
    public string TennantId { get; set; }

    public static MessageData Parse(string input)
    {
        return new MessageData
        {
            CorrelationId = GetValueBetween(input, "CorrelationId:", "Request for API:"),
            RequestForAPI = GetValueBetween(input, "Request for API:", "Caller:"),
            Caller = GetValueBetween(input, "Caller:", "CorrelationId:"),
            RequestedSchemas = GetValueBetween(input, "RequestedSchemas:", "TenantId:"),
            TennantId = GetValueBetween(input, "TenantId:", null),
        };
    }

    private static string GetValueBetween(string input, string startDelim, string endDelim)
    {
        if (input == null) return string.Empty;
        var start = input.IndexOf(startDelim);
        if (start == -1) return string.Empty;
        start += startDelim.Length;
        var length = endDelim == null 
            ? input.Length - start 
            : input.IndexOf(endDelim, start) - start;
        if (length < 0) length = input.Length - start;
        return input.Substring(start, length).Trim();           
    }
}
```

And now we can just call `MessageData.Parse(inputString)`, and we have a class with all it's properties set from the input string:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var message = @"CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
            Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5";

    var messageData = MessageData.Parse(message);

    // Now we can access any property
    Console.WriteLine(messageData.CorrelationId);
    Console.WriteLine(messageData.RequestForAPI);
    Console.WriteLine(messageData.RequestedSchemas);
    Console.WriteLine(messageData.Caller);
    Console.WriteLine(messageData.TennantId);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more robust solution if you don't know if the order of these elements returned from the API will change in the future:

```
private string GetRFAPI(string str)
{
    return GetSubstring(str, "Request for API: ", ' ', 1);
}

private string GetCaller(string str)
{
    return GetSubstring(str, "Caller:", ' ', 1);
}

private string GetCorrelationId(string str)
{
    return GetSubstring(str, "CorrelationId: ", ' ', 1);
}

private string GetTenantId(string str)
{
    return GetSubstring(str, "TenantId: ", ' ', 1);
}

private string GetRequestedSchemas(string str)
{
    return GetSubstring(str, "RequestedSchemas: ", ',', 2);
}

private string GetSubstring(string str, string pattern, char delimiter, int occurrence)
{
    int start = str.IndexOf(pattern);
    if (start < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = start + pattern.Length, counter = 0; i < str.Length; i++, counter++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == delimiter && --occurrence == 0) || i == str.Length - 1)
        {
            return str.Substring(start + pattern.Length, counter).Trim();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```